# css sheet not effecting php echo

Tags: php, html, css

I am using PHP to check a form. If the content is not filled in the PHP will echo an error message. I want that text to be effected by my style sheet. It is not. The CSS effects the rest of the page, just not that error text. I tried adding the span and class in with the echo and I tried adding the span and class to the html and just echo the text. No effect.

the HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="run.css" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0">
```

the PHP

```
<span class="errormsg2">
 <?php
    if(isset($notset)){
        echo $notset;
    }
?>
</span>
```

and the CSS

```
.pushme:hover{
    background-color: #eb5300;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.errormsg2{
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The PHP example I provided was from my attempt to put the span and class into the HTML and just echo out the text content.

Comment: Does `$notset` contain HTML?

Comment: what does $notset contain ? and did you try <?php if(isset($notset)){  echo "<span class=\"errormsg2\">$notset</span>";  } ?>

Comment: Or is your complaint rather that the span isn't centered horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that your file extension should be filename.php instead of filename.html
and because php is a server side language you will have to run your code in a localhost mode to see the change.
if you try to run php code in a filename.html the browser will comment your your php code.

```html
// filename.php file, this will work for you
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0">
    <style>
        .errormsg2{
            text-align: center;
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="errormsg2">
        <?php
            $notset = "test";
            if(isset($notset)){
                echo $notset;
            }
        ?>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He mentioned that the CSS effects the rest of the page, just not that error text... the php code itself is fine, the css is fine too. the problem is the file extension